# Custom string implementation, operator + overload memory allocation issue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to create custom string implementation in c++ and I have a problem with overloading operator "+". I want to append new string to existing one and when I try to allocate a new extended string, debugger allocates around 12 bytes more then it should. I have no control over allocation, he just ignores variable "length". Here is the code:

```
    class String 
{
private:
    char *ptrNiz;
public:

String(const char *niz = "")
    {
        ptrNiz = new char[strlen(niz)+1];

        strcpy_s(ptrNiz, strlen(niz)+1, niz);

        cout << "stvoren niz: " << ptrNiz << endl;
    }
    String(const String& refString)
    {
        ptrNiz = new char[strlen(refString.ptrNiz) + 1];
        strcpy_s(ptrNiz, strlen(refString.ptrNiz) + 1, refString.ptrNiz);
        cout << "Kopiran niz: " << ptrNiz << endl;
    }
    ~String()
    {
        cout << "Unisten objekt: " << ptrNiz << endl;
        delete[] ptrNiz;
    }

    int Length() const 
    {
        return strlen(ptrNiz);
    }
    int CharAt(int i) const
    {
        return ptrNiz[i];
    }
    void Ispisi()
    {
        cout << ptrNiz << endl;
    }

    operator char*()
    {
        return ptrNiz;
    }

    String operator+=(const const String& ref)
    { 
        const int const length = ref.Length() + this->Length() + 1;

        char *temp = new char[length]; // ignores length and allocates more space

        for (int i = 0; i < this->Length(); i++)
        {
            temp[i] = ptrNiz[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < ref.Length(); j++)
        {
            temp[this->Length() + j] = ref.ptrNiz[j];
        }

        return String(temp);
    }

};
```

Comment: I suggest you check [this binary arithmetic operator reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators), it has an example of an overloaded `+=` operator. Now try to compare it to yours and I think you will find a few problems with your operator function. One of the important things reft out of the example, is that it is an ***assignment***, i.e. an assignment to `this`. Judging from your question, I think you mixed `operator+` and `operator+=`.

Comment: Do you even null terminate the new string? It looks like you just copy the two strings in and leave a garbage character at the end.

Comment: In your description you say `operator+` but in your code you have `operator+=`.

Comment: Hello, operator should be +=, and we have found an issue, I did not set a null array '\0' at the end of the string. Of course, I will fix rest of the code errors as well.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> char *temp = new char[length]; // ignores length and allocates more space
> ```

All which your C++ implementation is required to do here is returning a pointer to a memory location with room for `length` bytes. Nothing more, nothing less. It is allowed to internally allocate more bytes, even though your code must not try to access them (or else the behaviour is undefined).

The low-level details of dynamic memory allocation is an implementation issue, not your code's concern.

A debug build is a very good example for a situation in which a C++ implementation may use extra bytes for debugging information. In fact, that's probably what is happening here. I suppose you are using Visual C++. As [its documentation (CRT Debug Heap Details)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx) says:

> When you request a memory block, the debug heap manager allocates from
>   the base heap a **slightly larger block of memory than requested** and
>   returns a pointer to your portion of that block.
>
> [...]
>
> The additional memory allocated by the debug heap routines is used for
>   bookkeeping information, for pointers that link debug memory blocks
>   together, and for small buffers on either side of your data to catch
>   overwrites of the allocated region.

Note that there are **very many other grave errors** in your code. I decided to ignore them for now and just answered the exact question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating twice, once in the constructor and again in the operator+= method. You also aren't deleting the pointer in the operator function so that memory is leaking. Either use smart pointers or provide an additional constructor parameter which specifies the ownership of the incoming pointer.

Comment: *"Either use smart pointers or provide an additional constructor parameter which specifies the ownership of the incoming pointer."* - Or just use `std::string` :)

Answer (score -2):

In your code please add the following line in to terminate the string with `NULL`;

```
String operator+=(const const String& ref)
{
   // You code goes here
    temp[length - 1] = '\0';
    return String(temp);
}
```

This will work as expected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While not bad advice (I saw it first ;) ), this isn't really an answer to the question.

Comment: Hi, I did as You said and it works. Of course, I will fix pointers issue.